# Degrees of parabolic subgroups

Tags: geometry, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, invariant-theory

Suppose a finite reflection group $G$ has the degrees $d_1,\ldots,d_n$. Let $G^*$ be a parabolic subgroup of $G$. What are the degrees of $G^*$. Since $|G^*|$ divides $|G|$ it is clear that the degrees of $G^*$ sould divide the degrees of $G$ but can there be more said?